# Trigger doesn't work in Production

Tags: trigger

I created a new trigger to update data and tested on the sand box successfully and deployed to prod org. But no data get updated on the prod org and there is no error either. Can someone please say why this happens, Thanks Jay

```
trigger TPValuesOnContact on Training_Plan__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    if (checkRecursive.runOnce()) {

        Set<Id> ContactIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Contact> contactsForUpdate = new List<Contact>();
        Training_Plan__c[] TPs = null;

        if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
            TPs = Trigger.new;
        } else if (Trigger.isDelete) {
            TPs = Trigger.old;
        }

        for (Training_Plan__c TP : TPs) {
            if (TP.Traineeref__c != null) {
                ContactIds.add(TP.Traineeref__c);
            }
        }

        List<AggregateResult> agrResults =
            [SELECT Traineeref__c i,
             sum(Enrolled_STM_2015__c) stmtotal,
             sum(Enrolled_Credit_2015__c) credittotal
             FROM Training_Plan__c
             WHERE TraineeRef__c in :ContactIds
             GROUP BY TraineeRef__c];

        for (AggregateResult ar : agrResults) {
            contactsForUpdate.add(new Contact(  Id = (Id)ar.get('i'),
                                                X2015_Enrolled_Credit__c = (Decimal)ar.get('credittotal'),
                                                Enrolled_STM_2015_temp__c = (Decimal)ar.get('stmtotal')));
        }
        if ( !contactsForUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update contactsForUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to add a lot more information before anyone can help...can you share your trigger code, any error message you get, what you are expecting to happen etc....

Comment: Does your test method pass and does it properly assert for results and cover the logic / business process of the trigger? I would be willing to bet that the checkrecursive.runOnce may be set to true by another trigger / process so the trigger never runs. Have you reviewed the debug logs to see what is happening?

Comment: I tested on sandbox and found the fields get updated. Then why it doesn't work on Prod org. There are no error massage either